# IncoherentInstances choosing wrong instance

Tags: haskell

When I create a new type with a Symbol in the constructor, with IncoherentInstances on, the correct instance for the type is chosen only when the symbol is filled in at compile time....

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, GADTs, KindSignatures, FlexibleInstances, IncoherentInstances #-}

import GHC.TypeLits

data Object:: Symbol -> * where
    Object :: Object sy

instance Show (Object "dog") where
    show _ = "dog"

instance Show (Object x) where
    show _ = "other"

main = do
    let name = "dog"
    print (undefined :: Object "dog") -- outputs "dog", as expected
    print (undefined :: Object "cat") -- outputs "other", as expected
    print (undefined :: Object name) -- outputs "other", I expected "dog"
```

Is there a way to supply a string Symbol value at runtime?  If this isn't allowed, why does it even compile (ie- when would anyone even want to use the assignment in the third print if it isn't resolving to anything but the default case?)

Comment: Your use of `Object "dog"` is incorrect.  In the type `Object a`, `a` must be a type, not a value.

Comment: @bheklilr It's with the `DataKinds` extension, so it actually works. I don't understand why the 3rd line works, thought.

Comment: The `name` in `Object name` is just a type variable -- there's no tie to the `name` in `let name = "dog"`.

Comment: @daniel, then why would it compile....  didn't I specify the kind of the parameter to be a string literal?

Comment: @jamshidh There can be type-variables of kind Symbol too

Comment: @daniel- Do you have a reference for what the Symbol kind can refer to?  So far google hasen't given me much info.  If you could put this in an answer below and it checks out, I'll be happy to mark it correct....

Comment: @jamshidh I'm happy to address this concern of yours, but I'm not sure I understand it yet. What do you mean by "refer to"? Are you asking what types are classified by `Symbol`?

Comment: I mean (using the example above)- (undefined::Object <whatCanGoHere>).  If I used Nat instead of Symbol, I could put "100" in that spot.  The documentation at GHC.TypeLits isn't very useful--all it says is "This is the *kind* of type-level symbols".  I guess I am asking what a Symbol is....

Comment: @jamshidh Well, the trite answer to "what can go here" is "anything with kind `Symbol`". It's not easy to enumerate all the things that can go there -- by analogy, consider `foo :: Int; foo = <whatCanGoHere>`. Of course `0` and `42` work; but any variables of type `Int` works, or a program to find the first six-digit prime, or a million other things. The situation with `Symbol` is the same: there is a rich language of types that includes literals, variables, application, quantification, coercions, type families... any of these things can be put there, provided the end result has kind `Symbol`.

Comment: I was just looking for some reference to that rich language (ie- why would something called "Symbol" refer to both a naked word token like 'name' as well as well as a string literal '"dog"')....  Nevertheless I think this might be going beyond this question, which has been answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haskell [GHC] has two [three] completely separate namespaces: terms and types [and kinds]. This is why you see this kind of thing all the time:

```
data Foo a = Foo a | Bar Int
```

which declares (among other things) *two* separate names `Foo`; one is a type-level name `Foo` which is a type constructor, and the other is a term-level name `Foo` which is a data constructor. Similarly, in

```
foo :: a -> a
foo a = a
```

there are *two* separate names `a`: one is a type-level name `a` which is a type variable and the other is a term-level name `a` which is a term variable.

The *only* interaction between the two levels is typing judgments: a name at one level may have a known classification in the level above. For example, the name `Just` at the term level is classified by the type `a -> Maybe a` at the type level; however, even here the names don't interact. If you want to connect a term-level name and a type-level name, you have to do some [very exotic trickery](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~eir/papers/2012/singletons/paper.pdf).

So when you write `let name = "dog" in undefined :: Object name`, you should read this as something like `let TermLevel.name = "dog" in undefined :: Object TypeLevel.name`; then it is clear that the `let` isn't helping and you might as well write just `undefined :: forall name. Object name`. Since there's many instances that match this type, and you told GHC you didn't care which instance it chose in such situations, it went ahead and chose one. It wasn't the one you wanted, but that's the price you pay with incoherent instances.

Comment: Typeclasses give another kind of interaction between types and *syntax* where, for instance, `"return ()"` has a value determined by its type. I'm not sure how to speak about it formally, but it's worth noting it exists and forms the core of a lot of said exotic trickery.

Comment: I chose this as the accepted answer, but a lot of the important discussion is actually in the comments above.

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but you can define a name on the type level, of course, by using `type`. So if you say `type Name = "dog"`, then `print (undefined :: Object Name)` works as expected, even with just `OverlappingInstances` rather than `IncoherentInstances` (which, btw, I would strongly discourage to rely on for anything ...)

Comment: @kosmikus- wow, that is kind of trippy.  It partially explains why a string literal can be a symbol (at least it is consistent with what type allows).  What good is this though (ie- why did the creators of Haskell allow this, what was the purpose?).  Perhaps I should spin out a new question.